# A separate loop slows down an independent earlier loop?

Tags: c++, performance, loops, for-loop

How can a separate loop affect the performance of an independent earlier loop?

My first loop reads some large text files and counts the lines/rows. 
After a malloc, the second loop populates the allocated matrix.

If the second loop is commented out, the first loop takes 1.5 sec. However, compiling WITH the second loop slows down the first loop, which now takes 30-40 seconds!

In other words: the second loop somehow slows down the first loop. I have tried to change scope, change compilers, change compiler flags, change the loop itself, bring everything into main(), use boost::iostream and even place one loop in a shared library, but in every attempt the same problem persists!

The first loop is fast until the program is compiled with the second loop.

---

EDIT: Here is a full example of my problem ------------>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "string.h"
#include "boost/chrono.hpp"
#include "sys/mman.h"
#include "sys/stat.h"
#include "fcntl.h"
#include <algorithm>

unsigned long int countLines(char const *fname) {
    static const auto BUFFER_SIZE = 16*1024;
    int fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1) {
        std::cout << "Open Error" << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    posix_fadvise(fd, 0, 0, 1); 
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    unsigned long int lines = 0;

    while(size_t bytes_read = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE)) {
        if(bytes_read == (size_t)-1) {
            std::cout << "Read Failed" << std::endl;
            std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (!bytes_read)
            break;

        int n;
        char *p;
        for(p = buf, n=bytes_read ; n > 0 && (p = (char*) memchr(p, '\n', n)) ; n = (buf+bytes_read) - ++p)
            ++lines;
    }
    close(fd);
    return lines;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // initial variables
    int offset = 55;  
    unsigned long int rows = 0;
    unsigned long int cols = 0;
    std::vector<unsigned long int> dbRows = {0, 0, 0};
    std::vector<std::string> files = {"DATA/test/file1.csv",  // large files: 3Gb 
                                      "DATA/test/file2.csv",  // each line is 55 chars long 
                                      "DATA/test/file3.csv"};

    // find each file's number of rows 
    for (int x = 0; x < files.size(); x++) {   // <--- FIRST LOOP **
        dbRows[x] = countLines(files[x].c_str());
    }

    // define matrix row as being the largest row found 
    // define matrix col as being 55 chars long for each csv file
    std::vector<unsigned long int>::iterator maxCount;
    maxCount = std::max_element(dbRows.begin(), dbRows.end());
    rows = dbRows[std::distance(dbRows.begin(), maxCount)];   // typically rows = 72716067
    cols = dbRows.size() * offset;                            //           cols = 165 

    // malloc required space (11998151055)
    char *syncData = (char *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(char));

    // fill up allocated memory with a test letter
    char t[]= "x";
    for (unsigned long int x = 0; x < (rows*cols); x++) {   // <--- SECOND LOOP **
        syncData[x] = t[0];
    } 

    free(syncData);
    return 0; 
}
```

### I have also noticed that lowering the number of columns speeds up the first loop.

A profiler points the finger to this line:

```
while(size_t bytes_read = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE))
```

The program idles on this line for 30 seconds or a wait count of 230,000. 
In assembly, the wait count occurs on:

```
Block 5:
lea 0x8(%rsp), %rsi
mov %r12d, %edi
mov $0x4000, %edx
callq  0x402fc0     <------ stalls on callq
Block 6:
mov %rax, %rbx
test %rbx, %rbx
jz 0x404480 <Block 18>
```

My guess is that an API block occurs when reading from stream, but I don't know why?

Comment: Is the inner `for` loop this second loop that you talk about?

Comment: Where is the second loop?

Comment: What function is being called when it stalls? Is that `read()` or `memchr()`?

Comment: It's normal for a system call like `read()` to be implicated by a profiler. This has to do lots of work in the kernel, so it's much slower than something like `memchr()`. But it shouldn't idle for 30 second on a single call, unless it's reading from a slow device like a terminal, waiting for the user to type something.

Comment: func1 readlines() and then func2 malloc(), then func3 readAgain() -- I hope that makes it clear, so I read from file, I malloc the size i need, then I read again to fill up my allocated memory. Also, it's read that stalls, not memchr().

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear, I hope... I know its confusing.

Comment: Without seeing the exact code, it's difficult to be sure what's going on, but my guess is that the optimizer is able to eliminate most of the first loop's code (if not all) when the second loop is commented out (dead-code elimination). By commenting in the second loop, the optimizer can't optimize the first loop away anymore.

Comment: Can you please post more complete example?

Comment: @HarryReed perhaps you allocate more memory than you physically have? (It will result in swapping once you start filling it in Func3 and slow you down to a crawl.)

Comment: ok I'll try to post a more complete example

Comment: @Innocent Bystander there is 3Gb RAM left after completely filling up malloc.

Comment: Please create the simplest possible example, then attach its full assembly.

Comment: Turn off all optimizations and then test it again.

Comment: I have disabled optimization with -O0. It had no effect. I've just posted a full example of my problem..

Comment: I don't really see how this would actually cause a problem, but it's the only obvious link between the `for` loops in main() that I can see.   In each `for` loop initializer, the code declares and initializes a new index variable named `x`.  I'm wondering if the second `x` is interfering with the first one in some way.  The fact that you've found that changing the value in `cols` affects the execution time of the first loop would support this possibility as well.  Maybe try changing the index variable name in the second `for` loop to something else and see what happens?

Comment: Try adding some `print` statements in `countLines` and comment out the second loop. Now run the program: can you see the print statements? Also, if you comment out the second loop, but print all the element in `syncData` is the first loop still very fast?

Comment: What does `time ./a.out` say?  Is your program spending all its CPU time in user-space?  Is there a lot of kernel ("system") CPU time?  Does user+sys add up to the real time?  If not, then your process is blocking on disk I/O (which is normal, since counting newlines should be fast).  But is the extra time with loop2 compiled in coming from CPU time, or from worse I/O?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My theory:

Allocating and touching all that memory evicts the big files from disk cache, so the next run has to read them from disk.

If you ran the version without loop2 a couple times to warm up the disk cache, then run a version *with* loop2, I predict it will be fast the first time, but slow for further runs without warming up the disk cache again first.

The memory consumption happens after the files have been read.  This causes "memory pressure" on the page cache (aka disk cache), causing it to evict data from the cache to make room for the pages for your process to write to.

Your computer probably has just barely enough free RAM to cache your working set.  Closing your web browser might free up enough to make a difference!  Or not, since your `11998151055` is 11.1GiB, and you're writing every page of it.  (Every byte, even.  You could do it with `memset` for higher performance, although I assume what you've shown is just a dummy version)

---

BTW, another tool for investigating this would be `time ./a.out`.  It can show you if your program is spending all its CPU time in user-space vs. kernel ("system") time.

If user+sys adds up to the real time, your process is CPU bound.  If not, it's I/O bound, and your process is blocking on disk I/O (which is normal, since counting newlines should be fast).

Comment: Thank you Peter, your prediction is absolutely correct! If compiled and executed without loop2, and subsequently compiled with loop2 again, the first run is fast, and afterwards slow, just like your prediction. user+sys does not add up to real time.

Answer (score 0):

From [THIS PAGE](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html):

"The function close closes the file descriptor filedes. Closing a file has the following consequences:

The file descriptor is deallocated.
Any record locks owned by the process on the file are unlocked.
When all file descriptors associated with a pipe or FIFO have been closed, any unread data is discarded."

I think you might have the resources locked by previous read. Try closing the file and let us know the result.

Comment: Given that this is a guess of what the problem **might be**, it is more suitable as a comment rather than an answer.